# How to get rc.local working for changing settings

Tags: startup

I started using Ubuntu and didn't really like how fast the mouse moved, so I found out the command to change it

```
xinput --set-prop 11 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4
```

Which will make it slow, but it's annoying having to type that in every time. I made a normal new gedit file "mouse_sensitivity" in my ~/Documents folder, and in /etc/rc.local I put:

```
sh "home/dylan/Documents/mouse_sensitivity"
```

Obviously, my problem is that this doesn't do anything when I restart my computer.

Quick note about the command I'm trying to use. It works and everything in the terminal or when I execute /etc/rc.local. If anyone else was looking for that command, beware that '11' is the associated number for *my* mouse, but probably not yours. And '4' is a really really slow speed for a pointer, but I just wanted to be sure that I'd notice the difference.

Also, I haven't edited it but when I execute /etc/init.d/rc.local it doesn't work. I can get those errors for you if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your command-line

```
xinput --set-prop 11 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4
```

to the file `~/.profile`.

Comment: Sorry for being so inept, but I can't find that file

Comment: the file `.profile` is located in your home-directory. In your file-manager enable the option `Show hidden files` to see the file.

Comment: Thank you. I opened it using the command    xdg-open ~/.profile and just put my command at the bottom. It's working now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler method to your mouse speed issues. From the Launcher select `System Settings` and then click on `Mouse & Touchpad` to bring up this screen:

[image]

From here you can set your mouse speed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this was the first thing I tried. I don't know whether it's because it's wireless or because it shares a transceiver with my keyboard, or something entirely different, but that option isn't available.